# Autosize jquery tooltip width to the longest line

Tags: jquery, jquery-tooltip

Initially I create a jquery tooltip text like below:

```
function setToolTipText(elemId, content) {
     $('#' + elemId).tooltip({
         content: content,
         show: 'fade',
         hide: 'explode',
         position: {
             my: 'left center',
             at: 'right+10 center',
             collision: 'flipfit'
         }
     });
}
```

Later, I change tooltip text for a concret elem by using below code:

```
var indent = '&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;';
var content = '<div style="display: inline-block;">' + 
              '<p style="white-space: nowrap; color: #FF8000; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">' +
              '<b>Name:</b> ' + elem.Name + '<br />' +
              '<b>IP:</b> ' + elem.IP + '<br /><br />' +
              '<b>Ping to ' + elem.IP + ' with 32 bytes of data:</b><br />' +
              (data.responseStatus01 ? 'Reply from ' + elem.IP + ': bytes=32 time=' + data.rtt01 + ' TTL=' + data.ttl01 : data.responseMessage01) + '<br />' +
              (data.responseStatus02 ? 'Reply from ' + elem.IP + ': bytes=32 time=' + data.rtt02 + ' TTL=' + data.ttl02 : data.responseMessage02) + '<br />' +
              (data.responseStatus03 ? 'Reply from ' + elem.IP + ': bytes=32 time=' + data.rtt03 + ' TTL=' + data.ttl03 : data.responseMessage03) + '<br />' +
              (data.responseStatus04 ? 'Reply from ' + elem.IP + ': bytes=32 time=' + data.rtt04 + ' TTL=' + data.ttl04 : data.responseMessage04) + '<br /><br />' +
              '<b>Ping statistics for ' + elem.IP + ':</b><br />' +
              indent + 'Packets: Sent = ' + data.sent + ', Received = ' + data.received + ', Lost = ' + data.lost + ' (' + data.percentLost + '% loss),<br />' +
              (data.lost < 4 ? '<b>Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:</b><br />' : '') +
              (data.lost < 4 ? indent + 'Minimum= ' + data.minRtt + ', Maximum = ' + data.maxRtt + ', Average = ' + data.avgRtt : '')  +
              '</p>' + 
              '</div>';
```

It works but jquery tooltip width is not resized automatically to the longest line. 
It seems like the line (text) spills out of the jquery tooltip width.

Any ideas?

Comment: Set the width of the div to auto in css

Comment: I have set auto for div's width as below: <div style="width: auto;"> but it is not working. Also I have tried <div style="display: inline-block;"> but without success.